# CSS How to make a container the entire height of the browser window

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a div that I would like to be as tall as the entire browser window. The only way I have found to do this thus far is to set the height to 927px: `heigh: 927px;` but this does not seem like an elegant way to do this.

This is all of the css for that page:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://media-cldnry.s-nbcnews.com/image/upload/newscms/2020_51/3436724/201218-cyberpunk-al-1020.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #404040;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.fields {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.avatar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I would like for the top container to cover 100% of the browser window. Then the body element needs to be as tall as the entire browser window.

As far as I can tell `height: 100%; min-height: 100%;` should be doing this but instead both the container and body are compressed to about 300px at the top of the page. What do I need to do?

If you need to see it, this is the page that the css is styling:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React from 'react';
import { Page } from './Page';
import { PageTitle } from './PageTitle';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import '../Styles/PlayerCreate.css';
//import S3 from 'react-aws-s3';

type FormData = {
  handle: string;
  role: string;
  avatar: string;
};

// const config = {
//   bucketName: 'cyberpunkv2',
//   dirName: 'avatars',
//   region: 'us-east-1',
//   accessKeyId: 'key',
//   secretAccessKey: 'key',
// };

function PlayerCreatePage() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>();

  const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <PageTitle>Create New Player</PageTitle>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="body">
          <div className="fields">
            <h3>Handle: </h3>
            <input
              {...register('handle', { required: true })}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Johnny Silverhand"
              className="input"
            />
            {errors.handle && <p>Handle is required.</p>}
          </div>
          <div className="fields">
            <h3>Role: </h3>
            <select {...register('role', { required: true })} className="input">
              <option defaultValue="Rockerboy">Rockerboy</option>
              <option value="Solo">Solo</option>
              <option value="Netrunner">Netrunner</option>
              <option value="Techie">Techie</option>
              <option value="Media">Media</option>
              <option value="Cop">Corporate</option>
              <option value="Fixer">Fixer</option>
              <option value="Nomad">Nomad</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="avatar">
            <input type="file" {...register('avatar')} />
          </div>
          <div className="avatar">
            <input type="submit" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PlayerCreatePage;
```

Comment: have you tried `html,body{height:100vh}`?

Comment: Ya that worked. I've never heard of vh. Thank you a ton. Why don't you write an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: `vh` stands for view height, I added the answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your `html` and `body` a full browser height:

```
html,body{height:100vh}
```

more on `vh` [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)